# Sending SQL through python

Tags: sql, python-3.x, psycopg2

I'm trying to use python to dynamically create sql.
I'm using psycopg2 for postgresql

I have a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM schema.table_name
```

But I would like to do the following:

```
table_name = "some_table"
sql = """SELECT * FROM schema.""" + table_name + """;"""
```

When I try to run this it throws an error, printing it reveals the sql is surrounded in ' sql_statememt '

I used php a few years ago and there was need to prepare statements to avoid sql injection, I'm assuming there is a similar issue in doing it this way, I'd rather not use the {} and %s methods since I sometimes need to do subqueries.

Suggestions welcome.

--------------Edit--------------

So after a bit more googling/reading I have this, but there are two sets of {} in this instance it just happens the tables are the same but come from different schemas. I tried adding a second identifier but it didn't like that. So how do I distinguish the two sets of {}?

```
    table_name = 'name_of_table'
    cur.execute(
        sql.SQL("""INSERT INTO pc_processing.{}(x,y,z)
                SELECT
                    st_x(PC_EXPLODE(pa)::geometry) as x,
                    st_y(PC_EXPLODE(pa)::geometry) as y,
                    st_z(PC_EXPLODE(pa)::geometry) as z
                from public.{}
                order by x,y,z;"""
                ).format(
            sql.Identifier(table_name)
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably overkill on the variables but this sorted it, just beware the order of the identifiers.

```
    schema1 = 'public'
    schema2 = 'pc_processing'
    table1 = 'pc_201407060711'
    table2 = 'pc_201407060711'

    query = sql.SQL("""INSERT INTO {}.{} (x,y,z)
                SELECT
                    st_x(PC_EXPLODE(pa)::geometry) as x,
                    st_y(PC_EXPLODE(pa)::geometry) as y,
                    st_z(PC_EXPLODE(pa)::geometry) as z
                from {}.{}
                order by x,y,z;""").format(*map(sql.Identifier, (schema2, table1, schema1, table2)))

    # print(query.as_string(conn))

    cur.execute(query)
```

Comment: Is this possible for other DB without using any package like psycopg2? Because I don't think there is package for every DB out there.